# Preserve scroll when hiding elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div containing a list of elements. By default, the list shows only 3 elements, and you can show more elements by clicking a "More" link.

Similarly, you can then click "Less" to go back to the initial view.

**The issue**

When I click "Less", the "More" button is not in the viewport anymore. I have to scroll up to see the list of items.

Is there a css way to have the list of items in the viewport after I click "Less"?

Note that `.container` needs to be `position: relative`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.js-more-less').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.js-hidden-group').toggleClass('_shown');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.js-hidden-group .-item {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group .more {
  display: block;
}
.js-hidden-group .less {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .-item {
  display: block;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .more {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .less {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="js-hidden-group">
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <a href="#" class="js-more-less more">More</a>
    <a href="#" class="js-more-less less">Less</a>
  </div>  
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can save scroll position in moment of click on 'more', then while someone clicks 'less' just add scrolling to saved position and do not forget about value. It should be deleted after usage for preventing some errors.

Comment: Please add javascript/jquery tags to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with css, but javascript can really help you here:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.js-more-less').on('click', function (e) {
    var height = $(this).closest('.js-hidden-group').height();
    var newScrollTop = $('body').scrollTop() - height;
    $(this).closest('.js-hidden-group').toggleClass('_shown');
    if (!$(this).closest('.js-hidden-group').hasClass('_shown')) {
      $('body').scrollTop(newScrollTop);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.js-hidden-group .-item {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group .more {
  display: block;
}
.js-hidden-group .less {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .-item {
  display: block;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .more {
  display: none;
}
.js-hidden-group._shown .less {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="-item">Some element</div>
  <div class="js-hidden-group">
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <div class="-item">Some element</div>
    <a href="#" class="js-more-less more">More</a>
    <a href="#" class="js-more-less less">Less</a>
  </div>  
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the outer div css `overflow: scroll` and set fixed `height` and `width` style attributes.  Then use jQuery's `toggle` to hide/show the inner div.